# script to move multiple database log files to another disk

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have many databases that need to have their log files moved to a new drive.  Is there a script anywhere to do this?  Something along the lines of

for each user database...
  alter database...
  take offline...
  move log file to T: ...

Comment: what have you tried? Which part is the problem? Getting the lists of the databases, taking them offline?

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this a few years back.

You'll need to change the @DestinationFolder value and adjust the query to filter the dbs.

Currently, this will move the log of all user dbs to the @DestinationFolder location. I'd recommend commenting out all of the Exec sp_executesql @CMD commands and running, to verify the desired commands are correct
:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE proc [dbo].[MoveLog]
as

--enabling xp_cmdshell will be required to do the file move
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
reconfigure;


declare @DBName as varchar(128);
declare @LogicalName as varchar(128);
declare @FileLocation as varchar(128);
declare @FileName as varchar(128);
declare @CMD as nvarchar(256);
declare @SourceFolder as varchar(128);
declare @DestinationFolder as varchar(128);

SET @DestinationFolder = 'E:\MSSQL\LOG'; -- Change this to the correct destination folder

BEGIN TRY

declare Db_cursor Cursor forward_only for
   select name
   from sys.databases
   where owner_sid  0x01;--user dbs only

OPEN Db_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM Db_cursor 
INTO @DBName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    set @CMD = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK immediate';
    Exec sp_executesql @CMD
    RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT ;

    set @CMD = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] SET OFFLINE ';
    Exec sp_executesql @CMD
    RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;

    SELECT @LogicalName =name, @FileLocation=physical_name, @FileName = reverse(left(reverse(physical_name), charindex('\', reverse(physical_name)) -1))
    FROM sys.master_files
    WHERE type_desc = 'LOG' and database_id = DB_ID(@DBName);

    --move the log file
    set @CMD = 'exec xp_cmdshell N''move "' + @FileLocation + '" "' + @DestinationFolder + '\' + @FileName + '"''';
    Exec sp_executesql @CMD
    RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;

    SET @SourceFolder = REPLACE(@FileLocation,@Filename,'');

    /* Update the system catalog */
    set @CMD = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = [' + @LogicalName + '], FILENAME = ''' + @DestinationFolder + '\' + @FileName + ''')';
    Exec sp_executesql @CMD
    RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;

    set @CMD = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] SET MULTI_USER';
    Exec sp_executesql @CMD
    RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;

    set @CMD = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] SET ONLINE';
    Exec sp_executesql @CMD 
    RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Db_cursor 
    INTO @DBName;
END

CLOSE Db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE Db_cursor;
--GO
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
   IF (SELECT CURSOR_STATUS('global','Db_cursor')) >=0 
   BEGIN
      DEALLOCATE Db_cursor;
      RAISERROR ('Db_cursor Deallocated in catch',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;
   END

   SELECT ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_MESSAGE();

END CATCH

exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;
reconfigure;
```

Comment: Script worked fairly well, but needed to run it few times as it for some reason skipped half(ish) of the DBs on each run. So added IF inside WHILE to skip logs that were already moved, and it worked fine. Something like IF(@FileLocation NOT LIKE 'E:\MSSQL\LOG%'), also moved the SELECT @LogicalName select as first inside WHILE, and the IF right after that.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very old post. But I think it's best to post this solution here than in a new post.

I needed this above solution but changed it for many more ROWS and LOG files at same time because of reducing down time (above script grabs only one file). I added test code to don't take database Ofline if the Destinationlocation is the same as SourceLocation. You can define different Destinations / Partitions for ROWS and LOG Files to.

One Step I missed to is handling of File ACL. At some situation there is a more-than-default ACL needed, especially for the Service or Instance Account. I added this step to. The ACL settings are handled with a simple Powershell script placed at @copyaclScriptLocation
The Script is from Jeffrey Snover

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Copy the ACL from one file to other files

.DESCRIPTION
Takes a file and copies its ACL to one or more other files.

.PARAMETER FromPath
Path of the File to get the ACL from.

.PARAMETER Destination
Path to one or more files to copy the ACL to.

.PARAMETER Passthru
Returns an object representing the security descriptor.  By default, this cmdlet does not generate any output.

.INPUTS
You can Pipeline any object with a Property named "PSPath", "FullName" or "Destination".

.EXAMPLE
PS> Copy-Acl Referencefile.txt (dir c:\temp\*xml)

.EXAMPLE
PS> dir c:\files *.xml -recurse | Copy-Acl ReferenceFile.txt

.LINK
Get-Acl
Set-Acl

.NOTES
Author:  Jeffrey Snover

#>
#requires -Version 2.0
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
param(
[Parameter(position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
[String]$FromPath,

[Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[Alias("PSpath","fullname")]
[String[]]$Destination,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[Switch]$PassThru
)
Begin
{
    if (! (Test-Path $FromPath))
    {
        $ErrorRecord = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord  (
            (New-Object Exception "FromPath ($fromPath) does not point to an existing object"),
            "Copy-Acl.TestPath",
            "ObjectNotFound",
            $FromPath
         )

        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($ErrorRecord)
    }
    $acl = Get-Acl $FromPath
}
Process
{
    foreach ($Dest in @($Destination))
    {
        if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($Dest))
        {
            Set-Acl -Path $Dest -AclObject $acl -Passthru:$PassThru
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Stored Procedure:

```
USE [master]
GO
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.objects
            WHERE   type = 'P'
                    AND name = 'MoveData' ) 
    DROP PROCEDURE MoveData
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[MoveData]
AS /* enabling show advanced options changing xpcmdshell */
    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
    RECONFIGURE;

/* enabling xp_cmdshell will be required to do the file execute bash commands */
    EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
    RECONFIGURE;

    DECLARE @DBName AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @LogicalName AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @FileLocation AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @FileName AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @FileType AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @OwnerSid AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @CMD AS NVARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE @SourceFolder AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @DestinationFolderDATA AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @DestinationFolderLOG AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @DestinationFolder AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @copyaclScriptLocation AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @SQLDataRootDir AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @InstanceName AS VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @Regkey AS VARCHAR(128);

/*DEFINE Your Default VARIABLES*/
    SET @DestinationFolderDATA = 'V:\MSSQL\DATA';  --change this to your destination Dir for DATA Files
    SET @DestinationFolderLOG = 'P:\MSSQL\DATA';  --change this to your destination Dir for LOG
    SET @copyaclScriptLocation = 'V:\SCRIPTE\1_Move_Data_and_Log\copy-acl.ps1';  --change this to your destination Dir
    SET @InstanceName = 'CLUSTER_EV'

/* set and create DATA Destination folder if not already exist */
    SET @CMD = 'exec xp_cmdshell N''IF not exist "' + @DestinationFolderDATA
        + '"\NUL ( mkdir "' + @DestinationFolderDATA + '") && "'
        + @DestinationFolderDATA + '" does not exist... created''';
    EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
    RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;

    IF ( @DestinationFolderDATA NOT LIKE @DestinationFolderLOG ) 
        BEGIN
            SET @CMD = 'exec xp_cmdshell N''IF not exist "'
                + @DestinationFolderLOG + '"\NUL ( mkdir "'
                + @DestinationFolderLOG + '") && "' + @DestinationFolderLOG
                + '" does not exist... created''';
            EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
            RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;
        END

/* get dataroot location for copy original ACL */    
    SET @Regkey = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.'
        + @InstanceName + '\Setup';
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @key = @Regkey,
        @value_name = 'SQLDataRoot', @value = @SQLDataRootDir OUTPUT,
        @output = 'no_output'
    SELECT  @SQLDataRootDir AS DataAndLogFilePath

/* Replace ACL with DEFAULT SQL ACL from Master.mdf Data Folder */
    SET @CMD = 'exec xp_cmdshell N''powershell.exe ' + @copyaclScriptLocation
        + ' "' + @SQLDataRootDir + '\DATA" "' + @DestinationFolderDATA + '"''';

    EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
    RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;

    IF ( @DestinationFolderDATA NOT LIKE @DestinationFolderLOG ) 
        BEGIN
            SET @CMD = 'exec xp_cmdshell N''powershell.exe '
                + @copyaclScriptLocation + ' "' + @SQLDataRootDir + '\DATA" "'
                + @DestinationFolderLOG + '"''';

            EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
            RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;
        END

/* end of adding ACL Sync*/
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE Db_cursor CURSOR forward_only
        FOR
            SELECT  DB_NAME(mf.[database_id]) [DBName] ,
                    mf.[type_desc] [FileType] ,
                    mf.[name] [LogicalName] ,
                    RIGHT(mf.[physical_name],
                          CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(mf.[physical_name])) - 1) [FileName] ,
                    mf.[physical_name] [FileLocation] ,
                    sysdb.owner_sid [OwnerSID]
            FROM    sys.master_files mf
                    INNER JOIN sys.databases sysdb ON mf.database_id = sysdb.database_id 
            -- use no databases with Service Account as Owner like System Databases
            WHERE   sysdb.owner_sid NOT LIKE 0x01
            ORDER BY DB_NAME(mf.[database_id]) ,
                    mf.[file_id]

        OPEN Db_cursor;

        FETCH NEXT FROM Db_cursor INTO @DBName, @FileType, @LogicalName,
            @FileName, @FileLocation, @OwnerSID;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
            BEGIN
                IF ( ( ( @FileType LIKE 'ROWS' )
                       AND ( @FileLocation NOT LIKE ( @DestinationFolderDATA
                                                      + '\' + @FileName ) )
                     )
                     OR ( ( @FileType LIKE 'LOG' )
                          AND ( @FileLocation NOT LIKE ( @DestinationFolderLOG
                                                         + '\' + @FileName ) )
                        )
                   ) 
                    BEGIN
                    -- SET Destination for different Datatypes
                        IF @FileType LIKE 'ROWS' 
                            SET @DestinationFolder = @DestinationFolderDATA
                        ELSE 
                            SET @DestinationFolder = @DestinationFolderLOG
                        SET @CMD = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName
                            + '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK immediate';
                        EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
                        RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;

                        SET @CMD = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName
                            + '] SET OFFLINE ';
                        EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
                        RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;

                /* move the DATA file */
                        SET @CMD = 'exec xp_cmdshell N''copy "'
                            + @FileLocation + '" "' + @DestinationFolder + '\'
                            + @FileName + '"''';
                        EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
                        RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;
                    -- added by Steffen Engel - copy ACL Information
                        SET @CMD = 'exec xp_cmdshell N''powershell.exe '
                            + @copyaclScriptLocation + ' "' + @FileLocation
                            + '" "' + @DestinationFolder + '\' + @FileName
                            + '"''';
                        EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
                        RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;
                        SET @SourceFolder = REPLACE(@FileLocation, @Filename,
                                                    '');

                    /* Update the system catalog */
                        SET @CMD = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName
                            + '] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = [' + @LogicalName
                            + '], FILENAME = ''' + @DestinationFolder + '\'
                            + @FileName + ''')';
                        EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
                        RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;


                        SET @CMD = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName
                            + '] SET MULTI_USER';
                        EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
                        RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;

                        SET @CMD = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName
                            + '] SET ONLINE';
                        EXEC sp_executesql @CMD 
                        RAISERROR ('Executed command: %s',0,1,@CMD) WITH NOWAIT;
                    END
                FETCH NEXT FROM Db_cursor 
                INTO @DBName, @FileType, @LogicalName, @FileName,
                    @FileLocation, @OwnerSID;
            END

        CLOSE Db_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE Db_cursor;
--GO
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF ( SELECT CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'Db_cursor')
           ) >= 0 
            BEGIN
                DEALLOCATE Db_cursor;
                RAISERROR ('Db_cursor Deallocated in catch',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;
            END

        SELECT  ERROR_LINE() ,
                ERROR_MESSAGE();

    END CATCH

    EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;
    RECONFIGURE;

    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
    RECONFIGURE;
```

Comments:
/* get dataroot location for copy original ACL*/
I Know the XP_REGREAD Part is not such a nice solution and better done with Powershell, but i don't know a better way than that to get the dataroot directory.
This snippet is for SQL Instances and easyly could changed to the default Path

Comments are welcome :)